# Remove all versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby, debian, apt-get, dpkg

I ran `sudo apt-get install ruby 2.2.*` and I think I unintentionally installed every version of ruby 2.2.*...

I really only meant to install the latest version of ruby >= 2.2.0.
Now my disk is completely full.

How can I reverse what I did and then install the latest version of ruby >= 2.2.0?

Comment: are you trying to pick a specific version for your project? if so, you can simply ignore that and use rvm or rbenv.

Comment: Did you really have a space between `ruby` and the `2`? Then you will have installed just one `ruby` and whatever matches `2.2.*`

Comment: Ya. What's what I figured because it filled up my drive. This is on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: On this computer, if I say `apt-get install 2.2.*` there are 742 new packages to install! - and 27 already installed. If I `apt-get remove 2.2.*` I'd remove those 27 packages too and the system would likely be toast

Comment: I think I'll just start over.

Comment: Can you find the `apt` log? Mine is `/var/log/apt/history.log`. This should show you exactly what was installed.

Comment: I know that feeling :). Sounds like it's the best idea if you haven't customised it too much yet.

Comment: If you're using raspbian make sure to use `raspi-config` to expand the partition to use the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get remove ruby 2.2.*` try this to remove everything. Better to install ruby version manager like rvm or rbenv. Then install required ruby version using rvm or rbenv.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. Please read it again. **My disk is completely full. I cannot install anything else.**

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get remove ruby 2.2.*`

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35927935/174728) to explain why

Answer (score 1):

The space between `ruby` and `2.2.*` is a disaster. `apt-get` sees those as two separate arguments.

On my system `apt-get install 2.2.*` says this:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ada-reference-manual-2005 apache2.2-bin camlp4 cernlib-base cernlib-base-dev
  ...
  ... lot more packages
  ...
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-randr-dev x11proto-render-dev
  x11proto-xinerama-dev
0 to upgrade, 742 to newly install, 2 to remove and 27 not to upgrade.
```

You haven't installed lots of versions of Ruby, you've installed `ruby` and every package that matches the regex `2.2.*` *and* the dependencies!

This is hard to undo, because there are packages matching `2.2.*` that are already installed on the system and probably essential, so `apt-get remove ruby 2.2.*` isn't going to help here.

It should be possible to look at the apt/history.log to find the list of packages that you need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `aptitude purge ruby 2.2.*`